# android studio RecyclerView width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, width

I want the width of the cell to change depending on the length of the inner text.
Currently, width = 160dp is fixed, but
If I put wrapcontent
[image: As you can see, each cell is set according to the length of the data, even if they correspond to the same column.]
As you can see, each cell is set according to the length of the data, even if they correspond to the same column.

The number of rows can be changed, but the number of columns is 4.

I want to go through all data content in that column and set the width of that column to fit the longest text in that column.

RecyclerViewitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_po"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_qty"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_material"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_info"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're going to want to do that, the `RV adapter` loads one View at a time until the `RecyclerView` is full. Every time a bigger `View` gets loaded by the adapter all the existing `Views` would need to be redrawn. Then if the largest view gets removed from the screen you would need to refresh all the views to match the new existing view. This will use a lot of resources to continuously reload the images and could cause the app to freeze. But If you are really keen on setting this up check out the following question.

[How to set textview height for the largest string in android recyclerview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67397109/3943340)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chips(Material Design) for your requirement.
https://material.io/components/chips/android#using-chips